# CVS integration with jenkins : authentication fail

Tags: jenkins, cvs

All my CVS build fail on jenkins with the following message. 
I check on the command line that my credentials were correct. Command line version of cvs is 1.11.22

This has been working for more than a year

I tried to downgrade the cvs plugin, just in case there was a problem with the new version.

We are using cvs with the pserver protocol.

Jenkins version : 1.590

CVS plugin version : 2.12

```
Building on master in workspace /storage/jenkins/jobs/VIF_TRANSLATION_TOOLS/workspace
Using locally configured password for connection to :pserver:mvn@cvs-java.vif.tm.fr:2401/u/cvs
cvs checkout -P -D 17 Nov 2014 17:45:24 +0100 -d workspace VIF_ENVDEV/VIF_TRANSLATION_TOOLS 
ERROR: CVS Authentication failed: AuthenticationFailed
org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.connection.AuthenticationException: Wrong Password.
    at org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.connection.PServerConnection.openConnection(PServerConnection.java:267)
    at org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.connection.PServerConnection.open(PServerConnection.java:352)
    at org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.Client$1.run(Client.java:374)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
ERROR: Cvs task failed
Retrying after 10 seconds
Using locally configured password for connection to :pserver:mvn@cvs-java.vif.tm.fr:2401/u/cvs
cvs checkout -P -D 17 Nov 2014 17:45:35 +0100 -d workspace VIF_ENVDEV/VIF_TRANSLATION_TOOLS 
ERROR: CVS Authentication failed: AuthenticationFailed
org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.connection.AuthenticationException: Wrong Password.
    at org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.connection.PServerConnection.openConnection(PServerConnection.java:267)
    at org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.connection.PServerConnection.open(PServerConnection.java:352)
    at org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.Client$1.run(Client.java:374)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
ERROR: Cvs task failed
Retrying after 10 seconds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solve my problem. It seems that all my builds using CVS had a configuration that overrides the global one.

I uncheck the this connection needs a password on all my cvs jobs.

Comment: Thank you, this helped. In my case the error message was 

`ERROR: CVS Authentication failed: AuthenticationFailed

org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.connection.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed. Response from server was: "E Fatal err".

at ...`